# How to use binding object across functions inside a Kotlin android activity class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I have this class in a file named MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {

        }

        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        fetchData()
        displayBudget()
    }

    private fun fetchData() {
        //how to use binding here? for example: binding.tvTotal.setText("0")
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use view binding feature on Android Studio to replace `findViewById`. How to use binding object (`val binding`) in `fetchData` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trial & error, I can use Kotlin's lateinit variable for binding object.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    //declare the binding object here 
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //initialize the binding object here
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {

        }

        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        fetchData()
        displayBudget()
    }

    private fun fetchData() {
        //I can use binding object here
        binding.tvTotal.setText("0")
    }
}
```

Comment: I would call it just a simple `variable scope` case...

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize binding as an optional var for the entire class and then set it in the `onCreate` function and that will allow you to use it on the `onResume` without a problem

here's how to do it

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
//what the below does is create a nullable object binding of type ActivityMainBinding
var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    binding?.fab.setOnClickListener {

    }

    setContentView(binding.root)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    fetchData()
    displayBudget()
}

private fun fetchData() {
//you can now access the binding var here by using the ? operator
   binding?.tvTotal.setText("0")
}
}
```

Comment: `lateinit` should be preferred because otherwise you have to litter your code with pointless safe calls. In both of your examples above, you would need `?.` calls for the functions called on the nullable views.

Comment: it can be used with both, but i prefer using nullabe in case something wrong happens with the garbage collector, this way the app won't crash

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    
        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {

        }

    }
}
```